# How to automate version number update process for my Eclipse plugin built with Maven

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, release, tycho, version-numbering

I working with a project similar to the project  [described here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseTycho/article.html).
So, it has a few modules in parent pom.xml:

```xml
 <modules>
    <module>../de.vogella.tycho.plugin</module>
    <module>../de.vogella.tycho.feature</module>
    <module>../de.vogella.tycho.p2updatesite</module>
 </modules>
```

These modules have a general version number e.g. `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` or without `-SNAPSHOT`. The feature.xml file needs to contain the same version number:

```xml
<feature
      id="com.my.feature"
      label="My plugin feature"
      version="1.0.0">
```

and:

```xml
<plugin
      id="com.my.plugin"
      download-size="0"
      install-size="0"
      version="1.0.0"
      unpack="false"/>
```

The files category.xml (in p2 update-site projects) and MANIFEST.MF (in plugin projects) need to contain the same value.

The question is: How to automate the version number update process in all these files using Maven?

I tried to resolve this problem using maven-release-plugin and maven-versions-plugin. The first plugin makes a lot of unused actions (like making a lot of CVS commits, which I do not use in this project). The second plugin only makes changes in pom.xml files and do not modify feature.xml, category.xml and MANIFEST.MF, or I used it not so good.

Comment: Where are the files located which need to be updated? Thinking about filtering of those files?

Answer (score 22):

There is a special [tycho-versions-plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-release/tycho-versions-plugin/plugin-info.html) for exactly this problem. It (intentionally) does the same as the maven-versions-plugin, but also updates the (redundant) versions in feature.xml and MANIFEST.MF.

Even more, the plugin also updates references which specify an exact version, like references to plug-ins in a feature.xml, or references to features in a category.xml. So in the end, all occurrences of the artifact versions are updated, like in a refactoring.

For references with exact versions, there is also an automatic update during the normal Tycho build. So if e.g. your feature references your plug-in in version `1.0.0.qualifier`, this version string is updated with the actual value of the qualifier, e.g. `1.0.0.201207171147`. You can make use of this functionality to minimize the number of places that need to be updated by the tycho-versions-plugin: Instead of specifying the current version literal in the reference, you can use the magic version `0.0.0`. This version is also automatically updated to the latest version as part of the normal build.

Answer (score 17):

I'd like to add some practical hints for less experienced maven users like me to [Tobias Oberlies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1523648/oberlies)' answer:

The goal `tycho-versions:set-version` will change the version of all projects that are referenced from the master pom. The version strings of the maven configuration files (pom.xml) as well as the respective Eclipse/OSGi artifacts (MANIFEST.MF, feature.xml, category.xml) will be changed consistently.

To run the goal from the command line, use the following:

```
mvn org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-versions-plugin:set-version -DnewVersion=1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
```

The `newVersion` user property, `1.2.0-SNAPSHOT` in this example, is the new version to be set.

The above command line will use the latest version of the `tycho-versions-plugin`. If a certain version of the plugin should be used, the `tycho-version-plugin` needs to be added to the `project/build/plugins` element of the master pom.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>  
  <artifactId>tycho-versions-plugin</artifactId>  
  <version>${tycho-version}</version>  
</plugin>
```

Replace `${tycho-version}` with the current version of Tycho or define a property with that name and the appropriate value.

Comment: Why would you want to define the newVersion in the POM?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Giving it a second thought, you are probably right in that it is very unlikely that someone wants to _store_ the new version in the pom file.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm!

Comment: In the pom he specifies the version of the Tycho plugin not the newVersion