# tycho-p2-publisher-plugin fails on build with maven-release-plugin

Tags: maven, tycho, p2

I am using the tycho-p2-publisher-plugin in order to create a p2 site which can be uploaded to Nexus as described at [Tool for managing/hosting own p2 repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344961/tool-for-managing-hosting-own-p2-repositories) - it aimed to be a work-around for the fact that Nexus does not seem to support hosted p2 repositories.

My problem is: the p2 artifacts are created fine and are even uploaded to Nexus whenever I do a snapshot build. However, when I try a release build, the build fails because of

```
[INFO] INFORMATION: I/O exception (java.io.FileNotFoundException) caught when processing request: /home/hudson/jobs/jobname/workspace/our.component.build/target/checkout/our.component.repository/target/p2content.xml 
[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy (default-deploy) on project our.component.repository: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact our.component:our.component.repository:xml:p2metadata:1.1.18 from/to releases (http://192.168.205.205:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases): /home/hudson/jobs/jobname/workspace/thirdparty/our.component.build/target/checkout/our.component.repository/target/p2content.xml (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden) -> [Help 1]
```

p2content.xml is not found, simply because it's not there. The question is, should it be there?

I am using the maven release plugin, and as far as I understand, during the release build process, all components are prepared, then checked in and tagged with the release version. After that, they are checked back out from the tag, and then the build is started. As obviously the release build is run for the checkout folder (as seen above: .../target/checkout/...), the problem seems to be that p2context.xml is created by the tycho-p2-publisher-plugin during the build, but not checked in, while later it is expected to appear in the checkout folder. I would guess that Maven should not expect the file there and try to deploy it to Nexus, but I fail to understand why is it expected to be there? And what's the right approach to cure my release build?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: The `maven-release-plugin` doesn't work with Tycho projects. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857153/how-do-i-create-an-eclipse-plugin-release-using-maven-and-tycho for alternatives.